# woocommerce REST API Get customer by email

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

Get customer by email

https://localhost/biobays/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/2 getting customer by id is working. But 
https://localhost/biobays/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/email/test@t.com or https://localhost/biobays/wp-json/wc/v2/customers?email=test@t.com are not working

I expect the user info do be retrieved.

I'm having an empty response.

PS: this work great on old v3 https://localhost/biobays/wc-api/v3/customers/email/test@t.com

Answer (score 6):

Joe,
I make a little test and this is the call you need to do to the API:

```
$params = array("email" => "test@t.com");
$getContact = $wcApi->get('customers',$params);

echo "<pre>";
print("<pre>".print_r($getContact , true)."</pre>");
echo"</pre>";
```

If you will test the url make the call like this:

```
https://localhost/biobays/wp-json/wc/v2/customers?email=test%40t.com&consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&consumer_secret=YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET
```

If no e-mail exists one empty array is returned.

Comment: Hello Rick, I will test your solution. If i understand well my issue is related to encoding %40 instead of @. I will check that and give you feedback. 

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Rick, https://localhost/biobays/wp-json/wc/v2/customers?email=test%40t.com&consumer_key=YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY&consumer_secret=YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET is working very well with curl but with Alamofire this is returning nothing. Very strange ...

Comment: I can't believe I finally found what I was looking for! Thanks for the answer. I wish I could give more than one upvote!

Comment: This seems to not work for REST v3? I need the same also for Get Orders by Email/Zip

Answer (score 1):

For new version api tested on 5.8.x , this seems to working fine

https://yourdomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?email=xxxxxxx@gmail.com